# PHP login redirect security

Tags: php, security, authentication, url

I wish to redirect users to the login page if they attempt to visit a page which requires them to be logged in. After logging in, however, I want to redirect the user back to their original destination. I've written a "redirect.php" script which is to be included on all such pages:

```
<?php
require "session.php";
if(!$user){
    header("Location: login.php?dest=".urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
    die();
}
?>
```

Then on my login page I have the following:

```
<?php 
$dest = "./";
if(isset($_GET["dest"])){
    $dest = $_GET["dest"];
}
?>
```

with the following JavaScript:

```
var URL = "<?php echo $dest; ?>";
//...
//upon successful login (via AJAX):
window.location.replace(URL);
```

Everything here works as intended but where does this stand from a security standpoint?

One vulnerability that comes to mind is something like

> `http://mysite.com/login.php?dest=http://phishingsite.com`

How might I best prevent something like this? Would regex be suitable here?

Are there any other security concerns with this type of thing? Perhaps a standard way of doing this? Or better yet, a method which does not use GET variables at all?

Comment: Anything speaking against using a session for this rather than an URL parameter?

Comment: No, not at all. I hadn't even considered the use of sessions prior to the user actually logging in. Care to expand? I see this approach requiring an additional page request unless maybe dedicating another page to the redirection...

Comment: I would consider using sessions as @Mario pointed out. Additionally, to stop against phishing, you could check that the domain is correct before redirecting

Comment: Are there any downsides to using sessions? Because I'm having a hard time coming up with any reasons to stick with GET besides the fact that I've seen them used before.

Comment: The one main advantage is you can send the redirect url to anyone, I do this quite often when telling clients where to go once logging in to their CMS - so it redirects them directly to the page they need to be on - see my answer

Answer (score 5):

The way you're doing it has advantages over a session based redirect because you have the ability to link people directly to that login with redirect URL.

The disadvantage is phishing as you pointed out.

```
http://www.mysite.com/login.php?dest=http://mysite.phishing.com/
```

The way you're doing this, using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` means you expect the `$_GET['dest']` to only include a path, not a domain.

So you could add a check in the login page where it sets the `$dest`

```
$dest = "./";
if(isset($_GET["dest"]))
{
    $parts = parse_url( $_GET['dest'] );

    // if there is no `host` key set in the parse_url array, then its an internal path
    // so set the new $dest
    if( !isset( $parts['host'] ) )
    {
        $dest = $_GET["dest"];
    }
}
```